# How Do I Use The CSS Background Property?

Tags: html, css, background

```
body {
  background: #fff url("milkshakeonthewindowsill.jpg") cover no-repeat fixed;
}
```

That's my CSS for my body, yet, it won't load the image, but somehow,

```
body {
  background-color: #fff; 
  background-image: url("milkshakeonthewindowsill.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

this code does. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, size `cover` has to be added separately:

```
body {
  background: url("milkshakeonthewindowsill.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: You missed the background-color #fff

Comment: true, I forgot it. However, when using a background image with size `cover`, an additional (or missing) background color doesn't make any difference - you won't see it anywhere...

Comment: True but just pointed it out if the image doesn't show up the color has to so it will make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

When using the shorthand property the order of the property values is:

```
background-color
background-image
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position
```

It does not matter if one of the property values is missing, as long as the other ones are in this order.

```
background: #fff url("milkshakeonthewindowsill.jpg") cover no-repeat fixed;
```

You are making use of background-size which isn't supported in the shorthand syntax and it should be in that order to work as given above. So, the correct syntax would be:

```
background: #fff url("milkshakeonthewindowsill.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
background-size:cover;
```

Comment: Do you know why the `background-size` property is not supported in the `background` property?

Comment: @Henry7720 I'm not sure but that's the background standard that had been incorporated for browsers when it was developed. It could have been that background-size was added later as a property so maybe, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Background size cover must be added separately:

```
body {
  background: #fff url("milkshakeonthewindowsill.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```